# Eloquent: eager loading with select constraints? possible?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Basically this works

```
Section::with('fields')->find($id);
```

also:

```
Section::with(['fields' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('*');
}])->find($id);
```

however:

```
Section::with(['fields' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('label', 'position');
}])->find($id);
```

will not load the relations.

I haven't found something in the docs about eager loading constraints except using 'where', so my question is, is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, turns out you have to explicitly include the `section_id` within the select clause :)

So this will work as expected:

```
Section::with(['fields' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('section_id', 'label', 'position');
}])->find($id);
```

Comment: Including the ID was key. None of the other answers I found mentioned this. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

I use the response of @iwyg, but the important thing is that the first element inside select is the field that join those tables (foreign Key).

In the example show by @iwyg the table fields join with the table section with the key section_id, thats its why is the first element inside the select. So is not just add the id for make it work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last days and I couldn't find any solution so now that I have found the solution I would like to share it with anyone who has the same issue.
 In order to use the foreign key's in functions, you need to give the function the foreign keys to for the tables so in this case if for example; you want to use section's relation so you need to give the function the values to find the relations so here it is if you have the relation like 'section_id' in fields table you need to use this code:

```
Section::with(['fields' => function ($q) {
$q->select('id','section_id','label', 'position');
}])->find($id);
```

also for Laravel 5.7* you can use Eager Loading Specific Columns too as the link below:
[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)